# Create a circle around multiple words in CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create one circle around multiple words.  Right now I have a circle around each word.  Below is the code I am using.

```
HTML
<span class="numberCircle"><span>Circle</span></span>
<span class="numberCircle"><span>all</span></span>
<span class="numberCircle"><span>words</span></span>

CSS
.numberCircle {
display:inline-block;
line-height:0px;

border-radius:50%;
border:2px solid;

font-size:32px;
}

.numberCircle span {
display:inline-block;

padding-top:50%;
padding-bottom:50%;

margin-left:8px;
margin-right:8px;
}
```

Comment: Why not have all the words within one span ? This is the simplest solution.

Comment: Also changing **display** to **block** would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You have created two different tags with "span" try deleting the tag without the class and try again. Having two tags one with and one without a class is redundant. Also the CSS is redundant as it is referring to two tags affecting the same markup. Dix this by creating a single tag:

```
<span class="class"> words </span>
```

Add the CSS to this tag and try again.

To add all words into this class use:

```
<span class="class"> <div> word 1</div>  <div> word 2</div> <div> word 3</div></span>
```

This will also all divs to have the same class used by the CSS style sheet

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can easily achieve it by wrapping your text with an element and use your `.numberCircle` class in that element.

**HTML**

```
<div class="numberCircle">
    <span>Circle</span>
    <span>all</span>
    <span>djsfkhjdajh</span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.numberCircle {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 0px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 2px solid;
    padding: 20px; /* Add spacing in the edges */
    font-size: 32px;
}

.numberCircle span {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 50% 0; 
    /* I dont think the margins are necessary in this way */
}
```

You can see an example of it working in here
https://jsbin.com/hekehatabu/1/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score -1):

Put all the word you want to circle inside a DIV, which has the class numberCircle.

```
 <div class="numberCircle">
    <div>CIrcle</div>
    <div>all</div>
    <div>words</div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Down voted because ``<div>`` should be used for the layout, while ``<span>`` should be used to style the text

Comment: @ub3rst4r who says? there are plenty of other `tags` you can use to style text, `strong`, `em`, `b`, etc... and even `div` if you'd like. While I agree I wouldn't change the markup around `span` element but it was the latter part of what you've said I don't agree with.

Comment: @Shomz I am all for semantic markup, but suggesting that `span` is the only applicable tag for styling text content is not true. Like I said there are a variety of tags that keep your markup semantic - apologies if it came off argumentative

Comment: @justinw No problem, I was just saying, despite the possible innaccuracies, that `span` is way more appropriate here than `div` and that I understand why he downvoted this.

Comment: @ub3rst4r this is not fair, if you where right <div> couldn't hold a class.  It's very usual to assign css classes to <div>.  There is no valid reason to downvote.  Please retract or give a wel founded argument to downvote.